# Symfony: Where Does autoconfiguration Take Place?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm investigating Symfony's Internals, and trying to understand the lifecycle of a service object.

A default Symfony 4.2 appliation contains the following in its `services.yml` file

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
```

The `autoconfigure` configuration value (which defaults to true) it marked with the comment *Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.*

Where in Symfony's code does this automatic registration take place?  Is this bundled up somewhere in the service container and/or the app kernel?  Or do services themselves need to define what their automatic configuration behavior is?  If so, where does that happen? Or some third thing?

Comment: Ther's a symfony PR for autoconfigure service registration https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/22234/files

Comment: Take a look at the framework dependency injection extension to see examples of autoconfiguration.  For the most part its basically automatically adding tags based on interfaces.  An application would typically do this sort of thing in src/Kernel.php

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand the question, [YamlFileLoader](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.html) seems to be parsing the file and updates the `container` to register services etc. Have a look `/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php` file.

Comment: @BentCoder Useful, thank you, but not quite what I'm after.  As I understand it, autoconfigue will do a lot of the work that was it was previously a developer's job to do when they wanted the Symfony framework to treat their service as something like a controller, or a CLI command, or something else.  I'm interested in see where that work happens if you're using the autoconfigure feature.